# expected has no actual declaration for common JVM in project without JVM preset

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I want to create a simple multiplatform app for android and IOS this is my common module config

```
kotlin{
    sourceSets{
        commonMain{
            dependencies{
                implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.61"
            }
        }
    }

    targets {
        final def iOSTarget = System.getenv('SDK_NAME')?.startsWith('iphoneos') ? presets.iosArm64 : presets.iosX64
        fromPreset(iOSTarget, 'ios'){
            binaries {
                framework('shared')
            }
        }
        fromPreset(presets.android, 'android')
    }
}
```

and this is my expected interface in my common module

```
package common
expect interface Response{
    fun submitResponse(res:Int)
}
```

the problem is IDE show me an error for Response interface that `expected has no actual declaration for common JVM`
 but I did not declare JVM as Preset.

these are the actual interfaces for android and IOS

```
package common

actual interface Response{
    actual fun submitResponse(res:Int)
}
```

Comment: What are the actual definitions for ios and android?

Comment: I update the question please take a look.

Comment: Nothing obvious. Can you post the project somewhere? Github, etc. The next thing I'd look at is if the folder you have your source in is correct. Must be `[source root]/androidMain/kotlin/...`